# Where is the Heart-to-Heart northeast of Theospiti Temple Ruins?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

The Skip Travel map for the Theosoir region in the Kingdom of Tantal shows a Heart-to-Heart icon northeast of the Theospiti Temple Ruins. I've checked the marked location near the airflow but I can't find a Heart-to-Heart in the marked location.

Where do I find the Heart-to-Heart northeast of the Theospiti Temple Ruins?

[image: map showing heart to heart]

[image: where the heart to heart should be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to start going up, which starts with that airflow and continues with a bunch more field skills (there's also a ladder jump involved).

[image: the heart to heart]